# Image matrix operation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have save a image in a matrix like this:

```
image1=imread('abcn.tif');
nfilas= tamanio(1);
ncols= tamanio(2);
nbandas= tamanio(3);

imagenn = zeros(nfilas, ncols, nbandas);
```

And my result is that:

```
 Name         Size             Bytes  Class     Attributes

  imagenn      4x4x3               96  uint16
```

And now, I want to graph the value of the same píxel on the three bands. I want to get the value of the first position (1,1), for example, and graph it. How can I indicate the position with a matrix?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix imagenn is square (4x4) and has 3 "layers" (R, G and B?). So, to get a pixel P on each "layer" you have to write P(1,1,1), P(1,1,2) and P(1,1,3). Note that Matlab's indexes start from 1.

You will have to plot vector P(1,1,:)